# Why is my modal popup not showing no matter what i do?

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

i have an already built website i built myself and i try adding bootstrap modals it doesn't show up no matter what i try, i even use other modal examples but either it is not showing at all or it is not fully visible or clickable.

below is my snippet

i have checked my files if css element is overiidding another but have run out of ideas!! i need help as i'm currently working on the project please.

```js
const openEls = document.querySelectorAll("[data-open]");
const closeEls = document.querySelectorAll("[data-close]");
const isVisible = "is-visible";

for (const el of openEls) {
  el.addEventListener("click", function() {
    const modalId = this.dataset.open;
    document.getElementById(modalId).classList.add(isVisible);
  });
}

for (const el of closeEls) {
  el.addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.classList.remove(isVisible);
  });
}

document.addEventListener("click", e => {
  if (e.target == document.querySelector(".modal.is-visible")) {
    document.querySelector(".modal.is-visible").classList.remove(isVisible);
  }
});

document.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
  // if we press the ESC
  if (e.key == "Escape" && document.querySelector(".modal.is-visible")) {
    document.querySelector(".modal.is-visible").classList.remove(isVisible);
  }
});
```

```css
.open-modal {
  font-weight: bold;
  background: var(--blue);
  color: var(--white);
  padding: 0.75rem 1.75rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
}


/* MODAL
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: var(--black);
  cursor: pointer;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.35s ease-in;
}

.modal.is-visible {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.modal-dialog {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 800px;
  max-height: 80vh;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: var(--white);
  overflow: auto;
  cursor: default;
}

.modal-dialog > * {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.modal-header,
.modal-footer {
  background: var(--lightgray);
}

.modal-header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.modal-header .close-modal {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.modal p + p {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}


/* ANIMATIONS
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
[data-animation] .modal-dialog {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s var(--bounceEasing);
}

[data-animation].is-visible .modal-dialog {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

[data-animation="slideInOutDown"] .modal-dialog {
  transform: translateY(100%);
}

[data-animation="slideInOutTop"] .modal-dialog {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

[data-animation="slideInOutLeft"] .modal-dialog {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

[data-animation="slideInOutRight"] .modal-dialog {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

[data-animation="zoomInOut"] .modal-dialog {
  transform: scale(0.2);
}

[data-animation="rotateInOutDown"] .modal-dialog {
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: rotate(-1turn);
}

[data-animation="mixInAnimations"].is-visible .modal-dialog {
  animation: mixInAnimations 2s 0.2s linear forwards;
}

[data-animation="slideInOutDown"].is-visible .modal-dialog,
[data-animation="slideInOutTop"].is-visible .modal-dialog,
[data-animation="slideInOutLeft"].is-visible .modal-dialog,
[data-animation="slideInOutRight"].is-visible .modal-dialog,
[data-animation="zoomInOut"].is-visible .modal-dialog,
[data-animation="rotateInOutDown"].is-visible .modal-dialog {
  transform: none;
}

@keyframes mixInAnimations {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }

  10% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }

  20% {
    transform: rotate(20deg);
  }

  30% {
    transform: rotate(-20deg);
  }

  40% {
    transform: rotate(15deg);
  }

  50% {
    transform: rotate(-15deg);
  }

  60% {
    transform: rotate(10deg);
  }

  70% {
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
  }

  80% {
    transform: rotate(5deg);
  }

  90% {
    transform: rotate(-5deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html class="no-js" lang="zxx">



<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="site.webmanifest" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/img/favicon.ico" />

    <!-- CSS here -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/owl.carousel.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/flaticon.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/stylemodal.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ionicons.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/slicknav.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/scss/stylemodal.scss">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/animate.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/magnific-popup.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/fontawesome-all.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/themify-icons.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/slick.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/nice-select.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css" />
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Preloader Start -->
    <div id="preloader-active">
        <div class="preloader d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
            <div class="preloader-inner position-relative">
                <div class="preloader-circle"></div>
                <div class="preloader-img pere-text">
                    <img src="assets/img/logo/ICON FAVICON 2.png" alt="" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Preloader Start -->

    <div class="navigation-wrap start-header start-style">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light">

                        <a href="index.html"><img src="assets/img/logo/ LOGO (1) 3.png" alt="" /></a>

                        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>

                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto py-4 py-md-0">
                                <li class="nav-item pl-4 pl-md-0 ml-0 ml-md-4 active">
                                    <a style="font-weight: 400; font-family: SF Pro Rounded, sans-serif; font-style: normal; font-size: 16px; color: #AEB0C1;" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Services</a>
                                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="what-we-do.html"><img src="assets/img/gallery/pointer.png" alt=""> What we do</a>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="dedicated-team.html"><img src="assets/img/gallery/pointer.png" alt=""> Dedicated team</a>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="product-engineering.html"><img src="assets/img/gallery/pointer.png" alt=""> Product engineering</a>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="development.html"><img src="assets/img/gallery/pointer.png" alt=""> Development</a>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item pl-4 pl-md-0 ml-0 ml-md-4">
                                    <a style="font-weight: 400; font-family: SF Pro Rounded, sans-serif; font-style: normal; font-size: 16px; color: #AEB0C1;" class="nav-link" href="about-us.html">About</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item pl-4 pl-md-0 ml-0 ml-md-4">
                                    <a style="font-weight: 400; font-family: SF Pro Rounded, sans-serif; font-style: normal; font-size: 16px; color: #AEB0C1;" class="nav-link" href="projects.html">Projects</a>
                                </li>

                                <li class="nav-item pl-4 pl-md-0 ml-0 ml-md-4">
                                    <a style="font-weight: 400; font-family: SF Pro Rounded, sans-serif; font-style: normal; font-size: 16px; color: #AEB0C1;" class="nav-link" href="careers.html">Career</a>
                                </li><br>
                                <li style="padding-left: 20px;"><button style="background: #489DF6;" class="genric-btn success circle">
                                    Get in touch
                                </button>

                                    
                                </li>

                            </ul>
                        </div>

                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <main style="margin-bottom: 0px;">

        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="open-modal" data-open="modal1">
              Launch first modal with a slide animation
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="open-modal" data-open="modal2">
              Launch second modal with a bunch of animations
            </button>
          </div>
          
          <div class="modal" id="modal1" data-animation="slideInOutLeft">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
              <header class="modal-header">
                The header of the first modal
                <button class="close-modal" aria-label="close modal" data-close>
                  ✕  
                </button>
              </header>
              <section class="modal-content">
                <p><strong>Press ✕, ESC, or click outside of the modal to close it</strong></p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo repellendus reprehenderit accusamus totam ratione! Nesciunt, nemo dolorum recusandae ad ex nam similique dolorem ab perspiciatis qui. Facere, dignissimos. Nemo, ea.</p>
                <p>Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure</p>
                <p>Nullam vitae enim vel diam elementum tincidunt a eget metus. Curabitur finibus vestibulum rutrum. Vestibulum semper tellus vitae tortor condimentum porta. Sed id ex arcu. Vestibulum eleifend tortor non purus porta dapibus</p>
                <p>Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure</p>
              </section>
              <footer class="modal-footer">
                The footer of the first modal
              </footer>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="modal" id="modal2" data-animation="mixInAnimations">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
              <header class="modal-header">
                The header of the second modal
                <button class="close-modal" aria-label="close modal" data-close>
                  ✕  
                </button>
              </header>
              <section class="modal-content">
                <p><strong>Press ✕, ESC, or click outside of the modal to close it</strong></p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo repellendus reprehenderit accusamus totam ratione! Nesciunt, nemo dolorum recusandae ad ex nam similique dolorem ab perspiciatis qui. Facere, dignissimos. Nemo, ea.</p>
                <p>Nullam vitae enim vel diam elementum tincidunt a eget metus. Curabitur finibus vestibulum rutrum. Vestibulum semper tellus vitae tortor condimentum porta. Sed id ex arcu. Vestibulum eleifend tortor non purus porta dapibus</p>
              </section>
              <footer class="modal-footer">
                The footer of the second modal
              </footer>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <footer class="page-footer">
            <small>Made with <span>❤</span> by <a href="http://georgemartsoukos.com/" target="_blank">George Martsoukos</a>
            </small>
          </footer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `modal.is-visible` class isn't offering a display option and it's not inheriting it from your clicking on the button. If you add `display: block`or flex or whatever you desire, that will allow it to actually appear. If you check your original code and then check the inspector, you'll notice that the modal is in fact there, it's just set to `display: none`

```js
const openEls = document.querySelectorAll("[data-open]");
const closeEls = document.querySelectorAll("[data-close]");
const isVisible = "is-visible";

for (const el of openEls) {
  el.addEventListener("click", function() {
    const modalId = this.dataset.open;
    document.getElementById(modalId).classList.add(isVisible);
  });
}

for (const el of closeEls) {
  el.addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.classList.remove(isVisible);
  });
}

document.addEventListener("click", e => {
  if (e.target == document.querySelector(".modal.is-visible")) {
    document.querySelector(".modal.is-visible").classList.remove(isVisible);
  }
});

document.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
  // if we press the ESC
  if (e.key == "Escape" && document.querySelector(".modal.is-visible")) {
    document.querySelector(".modal.is-visible").classList.remove(isVisible);
  }
});
```

```css
.open-modal {
  font-weight: bold;
  background: var(--blue);
  color: var(--white);
  padding: 0.75rem 1.75rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
}


/* MODAL
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: var(--black);
  cursor: pointer;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.35s ease-in;
}

.modal.is-visible {
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.modal-dialog {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 800px;
  max-height: 80vh;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: var(--white);
  overflow: auto;
  cursor: default;
}

.modal-dialog>* {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.modal-header,
.modal-footer {
  background: var(--lightgray);
}

.modal-header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.modal-header .close-modal {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.modal p+p {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}


/* ANIMATIONS
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

[data-animation] .modal-dialog {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s var(--bounceEasing);
}

[data-animation].is-visible .modal-dialog {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

[data-animation="slideInOutDown"] .modal-dialog {
  transform: translateY(100%);
}

[data-animation="slideInOutTop"] .modal-dialog {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

[data-animation="slideInOutLeft"] .modal-dialog {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

[data-animation="slideInOutRight"] .modal-dialog {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

[data-animation="zoomInOut"] .modal-dialog {
  transform: scale(0.2);
}

[data-animation="rotateInOutDown"] .modal-dialog {
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: rotate(-1turn);
}

[data-animation="mixInAnimations"].is-visible .modal-dialog {
  animation: mixInAnimations 2s 0.2s linear forwards;
}

[data-animation="slideInOutDown"].is-visible .modal-dialog,
[data-animation="slideInOutTop"].is-visible .modal-dialog,
[data-animation="slideInOutLeft"].is-visible .modal-dialog,
[data-animation="slideInOutRight"].is-visible .modal-dialog,
[data-animation="zoomInOut"].is-visible .modal-dialog,
[data-animation="rotateInOutDown"].is-visible .modal-dialog {
  transform: none;
}

@keyframes mixInAnimations {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  10% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  20% {
    transform: rotate(20deg);
  }
  30% {
    transform: rotate(-20deg);
  }
  40% {
    transform: rotate(15deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(-15deg);
  }
  60% {
    transform: rotate(10deg);
  }
  70% {
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
  }
  80% {
    transform: rotate(5deg);
  }
  90% {
    transform: rotate(-5deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html class="no-js" lang="zxx">



<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
  <link rel="manifest" href="site.webmanifest" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/img/favicon.ico" />

  <!-- CSS here -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/owl.carousel.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/flaticon.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/stylemodal.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ionicons.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/slicknav.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/scss/stylemodal.scss">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/animate.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/magnific-popup.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/fontawesome-all.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/themify-icons.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/slick.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/nice-select.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css" />
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Preloader Start -->
  <div id="preloader-active">
    <div class="preloader d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <div class="preloader-inner position-relative">
        <div class="preloader-circle"></div>
        <div class="preloader-img pere-text">
          <img src="assets/img/logo/ICON FAVICON 2.png" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Preloader Start -->

  <div class="navigation-wrap start-header start-style">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light">

            <a href="index.html"><img src="assets/img/logo/ LOGO (1) 3.png" alt="" /></a>

            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto py-4 py-md-0">
                <li class="nav-item pl-4 pl-md-0 ml-0 ml-md-4 active">
                  <a style="font-weight: 400; font-family: SF Pro Rounded, sans-serif; font-style: normal; font-size: 16px; color: #AEB0C1;" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Services</a>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="what-we-do.html"><img src="assets/img/gallery/pointer.png" alt=""> What we do</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="dedicated-team.html"><img src="assets/img/gallery/pointer.png" alt=""> Dedicated team</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="product-engineering.html"><img src="assets/img/gallery/pointer.png" alt=""> Product engineering</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="development.html"><img src="assets/img/gallery/pointer.png" alt=""> Development</a>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item pl-4 pl-md-0 ml-0 ml-md-4">
                  <a style="font-weight: 400; font-family: SF Pro Rounded, sans-serif; font-style: normal; font-size: 16px; color: #AEB0C1;" class="nav-link" href="about-us.html">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item pl-4 pl-md-0 ml-0 ml-md-4">
                  <a style="font-weight: 400; font-family: SF Pro Rounded, sans-serif; font-style: normal; font-size: 16px; color: #AEB0C1;" class="nav-link" href="projects.html">Projects</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item pl-4 pl-md-0 ml-0 ml-md-4">
                  <a style="font-weight: 400; font-family: SF Pro Rounded, sans-serif; font-style: normal; font-size: 16px; color: #AEB0C1;" class="nav-link" href="careers.html">Career</a>
                </li><br>
                <li style="padding-left: 20px;"><button style="background: #489DF6;" class="genric-btn success circle">
                      Get in touch
                    </button>


                </li>

              </ul>
            </div>

          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <main style="margin-bottom: 0px;">

    <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="open-modal" data-open="modal1">
          Launch first modal with a slide animation
        </button>
      <button type="button" class="open-modal" data-open="modal2">
          Launch second modal with a bunch of animations
        </button>
    </div>

    <div class="modal" id="modal1" data-animation="slideInOutLeft">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <header class="modal-header">
          The header of the first modal
          <button class="close-modal" aria-label="close modal" data-close>
              ✕
            </button>
        </header>
        <section class="modal-content">
          <p><strong>Press ✕, ESC, or click outside of the modal to close it</strong></p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo repellendus reprehenderit accusamus totam ratione! Nesciunt, nemo dolorum recusandae ad ex nam similique dolorem ab perspiciatis qui. Facere, dignissimos. Nemo, ea.</p>
          <p>Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which
            of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces
            no resultant pleasure</p>
          <p>Nullam vitae enim vel diam elementum tincidunt a eget metus. Curabitur finibus vestibulum rutrum. Vestibulum semper tellus vitae tortor condimentum porta. Sed id ex arcu. Vestibulum eleifend tortor non purus porta dapibus</p>
          <p>Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which
            of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces
            no resultant pleasure</p>
        </section>
        <footer class="modal-footer">
          The footer of the first modal
        </footer>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal" id="modal2" data-animation="mixInAnimations">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <header class="modal-header">
          The header of the second modal
          <button class="close-modal" aria-label="close modal" data-close>
              ✕
            </button>
        </header>
        <section class="modal-content">
          <p><strong>Press ✕, ESC, or click outside of the modal to close it</strong></p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo repellendus reprehenderit accusamus totam ratione! Nesciunt, nemo dolorum recusandae ad ex nam similique dolorem ab perspiciatis qui. Facere, dignissimos. Nemo, ea.</p>
          <p>Nullam vitae enim vel diam elementum tincidunt a eget metus. Curabitur finibus vestibulum rutrum. Vestibulum semper tellus vitae tortor condimentum porta. Sed id ex arcu. Vestibulum eleifend tortor non purus porta dapibus</p>
        </section>
        <footer class="modal-footer">
          The footer of the second modal
        </footer>
      </div>
    </div>

    <footer class="page-footer">
      <small>Made with <span>❤</span> by <a href="http://georgemartsoukos.com/" target="_blank">George Martsoukos</a>
        </small>
    </footer>
```

Comment: @tesseract If you found this answer helpful, please consider marking it as the accepted answer using the checkmark next to it. Thanks.

Comment: please sir, do you mean my `.modal.is-visible` class? i have checked my css and i have no `display:none;` set. or do you mean my JS?
please sir if you make me understand i will really be glad, i am a beginner.

Comment: okay sir, it worked!!! i had to add a new  css class `.is-visible` and add display to flex. but i still have a problem, when i try to scroll, it doesn't scroll but instead my background still scrolls. 

also this modal worked because i had to go online and search for a modal that actually works for me and my best guess is because of the JS,  a normal bootstrap modal from bootstrap site doesn't work. 
does  that have to do with a problem with my parent code too? i feel my site is so complicated. 

but once again, THANKS!!

Comment: @tesseract Yeah, that's what I was referring to. The `.is-visible` is what actually gets toggled in your code. So on the site when you have the modal open it would read as `class="modal is-vibile"`.  You don't have the display attribute set in your CSS but the browser is applying it *because* you don't have it set which is why I've suggested setting it explicitly so the browser isn't making the decision for you and that's what was causing the issue.

Comment: @tesseract For the scroll, just add `overflow: scroll;` to the `.modal.is-visible` and it should allow you to scroll so long as you're hovering over the model and not the rest of the page. I'll update my snippet to reflect that

Comment: thank you sir, i did add `overflow:scroll` but it did not work. also when i'm on small screen, the text just goes out of the container at the bottom and i can't see it, making scroll even more important.

what scrolls is the background even when my cursor is on the modal

Comment: @tesseract Make sure when you're hovering your cursor it's over the scrollable text of the modal, not the header or anything that otherwise isn't scrollable. In my updated code above it does work but you have to be in the scrollable part of the container. As far as mobile, you are likely going to want to work up a mobile version of this anyway as I wouldn't necessarily let it do that for you automatically. You could look into generic media queries: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp or bootstrap specific breakpoints: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/breakpoints/